# Logs in Kafka connect Distributed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm running Kafka connect in Distributed mode(On a 3 node cluster).
Are the logs generated by one connector in VM1 the same as VM2 and VM3?

The Connector which is running on 3 VM's is S3-Sink-Connector and they are running on the same port 8080 with the same group.id=s3connector.

Comment: Are they? Have you looked at them or are you just asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connector is given three tasks in the same consumer group, there would be unique tasks with different logs.

However, the initial startup logs will be the same, yes.

I believe each worker only generates one file, not a file per task it's assigned